# Stream Timeout 408 when using Python requests module

Tags: python, http, post, python-requests

I am facing an error in python requests module wherein I am getting Stream Timeout with a status code of 408 after 5 minutes of hitting a POST request.

I tried to add timeout parameter in the requests.post() function but still getting the same error

However when I use the curl command with parameter --connect-timeout 800 I can see that the client is waiting and doesnt get stream timeout

Please add your inputs if any idea on the issue

I tried using the timeout parameter in request module

For eg,

response = requests.post(url, headers = headers, data = payload, timeout=1800)

But still getting the response.status_code = 408 and response.text = stream timeout

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So if you receive a status code and an error does not pop up, it means that the other server cut the connection due to timeout, not your client that gave a timeout error, when you use requests and pass the timeout value it gives an error.

Comment: But when i use curl and specify timeout seconds it works fine. So its been mentioned that 408 is a client error . Is there something in the requests library which i am missing ?

Comment: Could you give more details of your code, for example the date you are sending and the like?